# Change image size on Alert

Tags: javascript, css, sweetalert

I'm using SweetAlert and for change icon image size I go to .css file:

```
.sweet-alert .sa-icon {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 4px solid gray;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: content-box; }
```

I have changed these values:

```
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
```

But I can't see the changes

If I remove .sa-icon. and add this in my .tpl page:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="sweet-alert">
```

The alert doesn't open.

I use this code for open Alert:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> sweetAlert({ title: "ADULT CONTENT", text: "ARE YOU OVER 18?", imageUrl: "dist/image.png", showCancelButton: true, cancelButtonText: "No", confirmButtonColor: "#ff0000", confirmButtonText: "Yes, I'am Over 18", closeOnConfirm: true }, function(isConfirm){ if (isConfirm) { } else { window.location.href = 'http://'; } }); </script>
```

The only problem is the size of my image. I can't change it. Suggestions?

Comment: where is the alert and where is the javascript?

Comment: I have added in first message. :)

Comment: are you using some plugin?

Comment: No, only SweetAlert.

Comment: why have you added `sweet-alert` class to the image?

Comment: It was a simply suggestion by a friend but nothing result. Using "<script type="text/javascript"> sweetAlert..." works all, the only problem is that I can't change the size of my image. My image is within a sized box, I think it depend by "box-sizing: content-box;"

Comment: when you're calling the `sweet-alert` in js, you can just increase the size of the image using Jquery.

Comment: I have deleted the code with class. it not works, not open the Alert. I'm calling sweetalert using "<script type="text/javascript"> sweetAlert..." How I can change the size of image?  I think it depend by "box-sizing: content-box;"  in .css file.

Comment: the reason it doesn't show up is because of this `.sweet-alert .sa-icon {` change it to `.sweet-alert, .sa-icon {` and it should work. notice the `,`

Comment: Repeat: Works all with "<script type="text/javascript"> sweetAlert..."  The only problem is the image automatically resized within a box.

Comment: ok. so you need to add another attribute `imageSize: '180x180',` when you're declaring the alert in javascript. this will increase the size of the image.

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: No, there are predefinite tags like ImageUrl etc., imageSize no. Example, for change color button of "Yes" I can add confirmButtonColor but for change cancel button color I have changed it in .css file.

Comment: yeah i know. but if you set the declare it like this `sweetAlert({
        title: "ADULT CONTENT",
        text: "ARE YOU OVER 18?",
        imageUrl: "http://placehold.it/350x150",
        imageSize: '180x180',
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonText: "No",
        confirmButtonColor: "#ff0000",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, I'am Over 18",
        closeOnConfirm: true
    }, function(isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {} else {
            window.location.href = 'http://';
        }
    });` it should work.

Comment: WOW! Works! Thanks a lot. :D

Comment: great. let me post this an an answer. please accept it

Comment: I can ask you a last thing? :)  How I set the height of Alert now? Because with image size changed the height is a bit too. THANKS!

Comment: I've posted my answer. please accept it. you can change the height of the alert in `CSS`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I check on CSS but not see height. ".sweet-alert {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 478px;
  padding: 17px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -256px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  z-index: 99999; }"

Comment: you can add `height` yourself.

Comment: you're most welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to resize your image, you must use the `imageSize` property of the alert and set it to the size you want. note to pass the `height` and `width` as two values separated by an **"x"**

update your JS like this

```
$(function(){
   sweetAlert({
        title: "ADULT CONTENT",
        text: "ARE YOU OVER 18?",
        imageUrl: "http://placehold.it/350x150",
        imageSize: '180x180', // add your dynamic height and width here
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonText: "No",
        confirmButtonColor: "#ff0000",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, I'am Over 18",
        closeOnConfirm: true
    }, function(isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {} else {
            window.location.href = 'http://';
        }
    }); 
});
```